# How to write date from a website, while crawling, into file.txt

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, datetime, web-crawler

`print str(item['dateUtc'])`
 This is a statement from my code that tries to print date and time. But its not working. The response from the api is

> 2015-03-30T00:05:00.000Z

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Do you flush the output?

Comment: @ justanothercoder: I did not follow you?

Comment: Is that string `2015-03-30T00:05:00.000Z` written in your text file? Then your code (previous edit) is working. Perhaps you'd like it in a different [time format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)?

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
import time
def tStamp():
    ts =time.gmtime(time.time())
    return(str(ts.tm_mday)+"["+str(ts.tm_hour)+"."+str(ts.tm_min)+"."+str(ts.tm_sec)+"]/"+str(ts.tm_mon)+"/"+str(ts.tm_year))
```

is nice to have on deck. 
alternatively

```
def tStamp():
    ts =time.gmtime(time.time())
    return(str(ts.tm_yday)+"["+str(ts.tm_hour)+"."+str(ts.tm_min)+"."+str(ts.tm_sec)+"]/"+str(ts.tm_year))
```

The documentation here is relevant
https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html

as far as the scraping goes I would recommend scrapy over urllib2 ... both are usable.